# Hiding the keyboard after typing in EditText view

Tags: java, android

I came across this piece of code but I am wondering what this code does and what exactly is InputMethodManager and where should I type in this code in my class? Will it go in the onCreate() method or should I make a new method? And again, I want to understand how this method works.

Thanks for your answer in advance :) I appreciate the help

```
    InputMethodManager inputManager = 
    (InputMethodManager) context.
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
    this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadoc of InputMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) is quite descriptive about it

> Central system API to the overall input method framework (IMF) architecture, which arbitrates interaction between applications and the current input method. You can retrieve an instance of this interface with Context.getSystemService().

In your particular case you are interseted in this use case

> An input method (IME) implements a particular interaction model allowing the user to generate text. The system binds to the current input method that is use, causing it to be created and run, and tells it when to hide and show its UI. Only one IME is running at a time.

Also from the description of  [hideSoftInputFromWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromWindow%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29) you can extract

> `public boolean hideSoftInputFromWindow (IBinder windowToken, int flags)`
>
> Synonym for hideSoftInputFromWindow(IBinder, int, ResultReceiver) without a result: request to hide the soft input window from the context of the window that is currently accepting input.
>   Parameters
>
> `windowToken  IBinder`: The token of the window that is making the request, as returned by **View.getWindowToken()**.
>
> `flags    int`: Provides additional operating flags. Currently may be 0 or have the HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY bit set.

This makes `this` in your code refer to a `View`, so that code is part of a class that `extends View`

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard) is an example of its usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Please don't add code-only answers. Add a brief explanation of your answer as wel.